# why the trim function is mandatory when compare responseText

Tags: php, ajax

While testing some **Ajax** and **PHP** code I stumbled an issue with **AJAX**'s `responseText`. When I use it without `trim()` a comparison in inside the function registration (see **js.js**) fails. I have verified if the response of the php code does not include a newline (see **registration.php**).

**form.php**

```
<?php?>
<html>
  <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src=".js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form>
        <div> 
          Name : <input type="text" id="name"><br />
          LastName : <input type="text" id="lastname"><br />

          <input type="button" value="send" onclick="registration()">                   
          <div id="message"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**js.js**

```
function getRequestHttp()
{
  var requestHTTP;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    requestHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(requestHttp.overrideMimeType)    
      requestHttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml'); 
  }
  return requestHttp;
}

function getDataForm() {
  var name,lastname,all;
  name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;

  all = "name="+name+"&lastname="+lastname;

  return all;
}

function registration()
{  
  req.open('POST','inscription.php',false);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-
  urlencoded'); 
  req.send(getDataForm());
  if(req.readyState==4) 
  {
    if(req.status==200)
    {
      //alert(req.responseText);
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";

      if (req.responseText.trim()=="no") 
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "already exists";
      else if (req.responseText.trim()!="no")
      {                 
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "registration succeeded";                
      }
      else
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "problem ";
    }
    else
      alert("Error :"+req.status+",wrong request");
  }
  return true;
}
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/plain"); 
  $conn=pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=data user=user password=pass")
        or die ("Connexion Impossible".pg_last_error());
  $name= $_POST['name'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

  $request="SELECT registration('$name','$lastname')";
  $res=pg_query($conn,$request) or die('damn ' . pg_last_error());
  $code=pg_fetch_row($res)[0];
  if ($code==0) echo "no"; else echo $code;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the review

Answer (score 0):

Because some times the spaces are being concatenated and your condition doesn't fulfill what you want. so for we use trim to avoid white spaces from both sides of results. Lets say we got success message from ajax request and we wrote condition like this :

```
if(response.message == "success"){
//do this
}else{
//do this
}
```

So in this case the response messages sometime comes with some white spaces appended thats why we use trim.

```
var response_msg = response.message;
if(response_msg.trim() == "success"){
//do this
}else{
//do this
}
```

This was the whole scenario i faced. If i am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: but if i force the response to not have the space appended as i did in my psql function : $code=pg_fetch_row($res)[0];  if ($code==0) echo "no"; else echo $code;   We can see here that there's no space before "no"